# How to install curl and libcurl in kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I want to install `curl` and `libcurl` in my Kali Linux.

In this website: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html. I use Kali Linux so my OS is Debian. But when I click to download, it says I have to select from:

- wheezy (oldstable)
- jessie (stable)
- stretch (testing)
- sid (unstable)

Which one should I choose?

I use latest version of Kali Linux 64-bit from this URL: https://www.kali.org/downloads/.

Next question is, what architecture is best for me? What should I choice? They have:

`amd64`
 `arm64`
 `armel` 
 `armhf`
 `i386` 
 `mips` 
 `mipsel` 
 `powerpc` 
 `ppc64el` 
 `s390x`

I don't know and understand that part.

After download, what command to run in terminal to install it?

Comment: > For your information: Kali Linux 2.0 is based on Debian Jessie. This is right but if we are speaking about the latest version of Kali linux it is not Kali linux 2.0 (deprecated) but **kali rolling**
The latest ISO is called **2016.2** and that the one that is used by *sukihinata*
Kali rolling is based on **Debian SID** (not jessie) Anyway, both version include (of course) curl and it dependency and, as suggested by *techraf*, the fatest and safest way is to use Kali rolling repositories to install curl.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of struggling with manual install, use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

---

For your information: Kali Linux 2.0 is based on Debian Jessie.

The architecture depends on the hardware you run on. As you said you were running 64-bit, most probably `amd64` is for you.

Answer (score 0):

1)install `build-essential`

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Go to `/usr/local/src` floder

```
cd /usr/local/src
```

Download latest `Curl` package from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) using:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.48.0.tar.gz
```

Unzip

```
tar -xvzf curl-7.48.0.tar.gz
rm *.gz
cd curl-7.48.0
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

2) The best architecture is `amd64`
`