# Unable to use curl with cookie-jar

Tags: curl, http, https

I am trying to use curl for login request automation. Here, use of cookie-jar is must. When I use ***--cooki-jar cjar*** option, it shows following error.

```
root@kali:~# curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /root/Desktop/Curl/ \ https://www.google.com
curl: (1) Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

When I did bit of googling around it, [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274286/how-to-install-curl-and-libcurl-in-kali-linux) says that ***libcurl3*** and [here they say that need to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821186/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl) ***libssl-dev***.

When I verified my system for both the libraries, in my Kali Linux box, latest versions are available. Still it is showing the error. So could someone help me to solve this issue.

**System details:**

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -s libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 6908
Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
```

Multi-Arch: same
    Source: openssl
    Version: 1.1.0g-2
    Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2)
    Recommends: libssl-doc
    Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
    Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
    This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
    and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
    Internet.
 .
    It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl
    and libcrypto.
    Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -s libcurl3
Package: libcurl3
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 649
Maintainer: Alessandro Ghedini <ghedo@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: curl
Version: 7.57.0-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libcomerr2 (>= 1.01), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg), libidn2-0 (>= 0.6), libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libnghttp2-14 (>= 1.12.0), libpsl5 (>= 0.13.0), librtmp1 (>= 2.4+20131018.git79459a2-3~), libssh2-1 (>= 1.7.0), libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: ca-certificates
Description: easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
libcurl is an easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library, supporting DICT,
FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S,
RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP.
```

.
    libcurl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP
    form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic,
    Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos), file transfer resume, http proxy tunneling
    and more!
 .
    libcurl is free, thread-safe, IPv6 compatible, feature rich, well supported,
    fast, thoroughly documented and is already used by many known, big and
    successful companies and numerous applications.
 .
    SSL support is provided by OpenSSL.
    Homepage: http://curl.haxx.se

Comment: what does `curl --version | grep Protocols` show?

Answer (score 1):

You have unexpected backslash in command and also **--output** should be a filename. Try this:

```
curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /root/Desktop/Curl/output.html https://www.google.com
```